# python: OpenCV depth of image unsupported (CV_64F)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

So, I'm trying to show a binary picture with only black and white using this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

x_img = cv2.imread("lenac.tif")

x_img_g = cv2.cvtColor(x_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

y = x_img_g > 128

cv2.imshow("", y*1.0)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex5.py", line 11, in <module>
cv2.imshow("", y*1.0)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) c:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:261: error: (-2:Unspecified 
error) >in function '__cdecl cv::CvtHelper<struct 
cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct 
cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class 
cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
>Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 6 (CV_64F).
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

try `cv2.imshow("", y.astype('float32'))`
or `cv2.imshow("", y.astype('uint8') * 255)`

`CV_64F` means the numpy array `dtype` is `float64` (64-bit floating-point).

opencv imshow only works with `float32` (32-bit floating point) where the range for the pixel values is `0.0-1.0` or `uint8` (unsigned 8-bit) where the range is `0-255`

Since `y` was a `bool`, converting it to a number means converting `True` to `1`

for `float32`, that is fine because 1 is the maximum for the imshow range

if you use `uint8`, that means you're trying to display pixels of value `1/255` (since the maximum imshow range for `uint8` is 255) which will be barely visible, so you can multiply by 255 to bring those pixels to max and appear as bright white pixels

Comment: Hey! The first one didn't work, but the second one did. Thanks!

Comment: What if you want to keep the range -1, +1?

Comment: @JürgenK. you cannot use cv2.imshow() with other than float32 [0.0-1.0] or uint8 [0-255]. you will need to change to range [0-255] by doing `y_copy=((y+1)*255/2).astype('uint8')` and using y_copy for imshow()

Answer (score 6):

Just change the type of NumPy array since the image is nothing but NumPy array

```py
cv2.imshow("image", image.astype(np.uint8))
```

It worked fine for me.

Comment: Thank's, works fine, and very simple to use